# Name for a folder that has all of your PSD's, AI's, SVG's, etc

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, work

My project folders at work have different subfolders for wireframes, comps, and prototypes, but I want to have subfolders for the actual .psd, .ai, .svg, etc. files to separate them from the many flattened jpegs, pngs, and gifs.

Is there a name for "unflattened editor files", instead of making separate "PSD", "AI", etc. folders?

I'm struggling to come up with a word for that.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/103637/how-to-keep-design-files-organized-on-your-computer/103638#103638 and https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55629/what-is-your-file-naming-convention-you-use-for-version-control/55633#55633

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I voted to close this.. it is *way* too opinion-based in my opinion. :)

For what it's worth I use a directory titled **"Working"** for construction files.

Then a directory titled **"Images"** for final images to be used.

All my projects essentially have the same directory structure....

- [Project]

  - [Client files]
  - [Images]
  - [Working]
  - project.indd
  - project.pdf
  - project.pdfx
  - [Build] (directory if web project)
  - [Older] (Backup directory of previous project file iterations. Basically I send the client a proof on the 10th.. they get back to me on the 15th. I copy the file from 10th into this directory, then make changes on the original file from the 10th. This allows me to revert to a previous proof if it's ever needed.)

Within the various directories you can add additional subdirectories if you want. You can do `Working -> Raster` or `Working -> PSD`, whatever. But by putting it in the "Working" directory I know it'll be the live, unflattened, editable, file.

Comment: I'm ok with it being closed. "working" works for me. I mostly develop and there are set conventions for folder names like "dist", "src", "lib". I was looking for clarity on the convention for the mentioned file types.

Answer (score 0):

### Image Files

They are all types of image files so you could you that.

or

### Graphics Files

Image file definition:

> Image files are composed of digital data in one of these formats that
>   can be rasterized for use on a computer display or printer. An image
>   file format may store data in uncompressed, compressed, or vector
>   formats.

Answer (score 0):

Source files /Sources? 
This is how I ususally structure my projects:

**Project Name**

--Assets (this could be fonts, photos, etc)

--Sources (ai, psd, etc)

--Exports (pdf, jpg, etc)